# Ajax falla al enviar datos en asp.net

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

En la pagina **Puzzle.aspx** ego el siguente boton:

```
  <figure><asp:ImageButton id="puzzle1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/puzzle1.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive image" OnClientClick="showModel('uno'); return false" /></figure>
```

Que invoca la funcion `showModel` pasandole como parametro un String "uno".

Declaracion de la funcion:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function showModel(variable) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Puzzle.aspx/addSession",
            data: "{'hotelcode':'" + variable + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("ok");
                $('.modal').modal();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

En el caso de exito, debe mostrar una modal, en el caso e fallo, mostraria una alerta con el mensaje "error".

Codigo c# de la pagina **Puzzle.aspx**:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void addSession(String hotelcode)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["tipoPuzzle"] = hotelcode;

}
```

Siempre me muestra la alerta con error, nunca va por el success para mostrar la ventana modal.

Alguno me puede dar una mano con este problema por favor?

Comment: Quiza se por que tienes: data: "{'hotelcode':'" + variable + "'}", en lugar de: data: {hotelcode: variable },.

Comment: Probe sacarle todas as comillas, sigue tirando el error

Comment: Intenta imprimir que error es con: alert("error: ", err);

Comment: @LuiscYm ninguno, esta vacia la variable err

Comment: Corrigeme si estoy mal. [No se mucho de aspx], pero cuando un metodo es void, se supone que no devuelve nada, por lo que si va a devolver una cadena debería ser "public static string", no es asi?

Comment: @LuiscYm exactamente, void o devuelve nada. El proposito del ajax, es pasarle el parametro a esa funcion static void, para que esta cambie el valor de la variable de session

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76670/discussion-between-luiscym-and-oren-diaz).

Answer (score 1):

El error esta aca:

```
data: "{'hotelcode':'" + variable + "'}",
```

Deberia ser:

```
data: '{"hotelcode":"' + variable + '"}',
```

Comment: sigue tirando el error

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo pude solucionar:

En la consola de desarrollador del browser me tiraba **error 401 not autorized**

Ajax quedo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function showModel(variable) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("Puzzle.aspx/addSession") %>',
            data: '{"hotelcode":"' + variable + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert("ok");
                $('.modal').modal();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error: ", err);  
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Y dentro del `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` cambie la linea

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

a

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```